# How to get response from HTTP web service in HTTPS supported GWT application?

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, https

I have to call a `HTTP` web service written in `C#` from my `GWT applicaiton`, which runs over `HTTPS`.

But because of HTTP web service, every time i am getting an error: `not allowed insecure content`, which create a problem to load the content of page on each browsers.

Is there are any way to change allow this insecure content on each browser with java code?

Comment: Could you provide code samples of your HTTP client? Which part is throwing this error? Is it your C# application?

Comment: @Nebelmann It is not throwing any error. I checked it on fire bug (mozilla) , console (chrome). When i click to allow the insecure content. It runs fine

Comment: Is your HTTPS certificate valid? Does your browser show some kind of "red lock" next to the URL?

Comment: I didn't got you, My web service is running on HTTP and my application is running on HTTPS (certificate and rest of everything is fine). It is happening because i am trying to access HTTp url from HTTPS hosted aplication, and i can't make that web service as HTTPS (due to some problem)